# variable string becomes null

Tags: c#, asp.net

I don't understand why my variable 'ver' declare as a string become "null" in my sql request when I use my function 'Button1_Click', whereas in my function 'Menu1_MenuItemClick' this variable 'ver' isn't "null" ...

```
public partial class Page_Admin : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public string ver;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {    
    }

public void Menu1_MenuItemClick(object sender, MenuEventArgs e)
{     
    if (e.Item.Parent != null)
    {
        switch (e.Item.Parent.Value)
        {
            case "BP":
            try
            {
                string url1 = "my_url";
                HtmlWeb web1 = new HtmlWeb();
                HtmlDocument doc1 = web1.Load(url1);
                var version1 = doc1.GetElementbyId("title");
                TextBox2.Text = version1.InnerHtml;
                ver = version1.InnerHtml;          
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Label3.Text = "Error:" + ex;
            }
            break;

            case "OL":
            ..........
         }
  .............
     }
  .............
 }

public void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string connectionString = null;
    SqlConnection connection;
    SqlCommand command;
    string sql = null;

    connectionString = @"...";

    sql = "INSERT INTO dbo.BP (appli, version, date, mode, variante) VALUES ('test','" + ver +"','11/12/2014','connecté','N+1');";

    connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString); 
    connection.Open();
    command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    command.Dispose();
    connection.Close();
}
```

Comment: Field values are not maintained between requests, a new instance is created with every request. So when you set `ver` in `Menu1_MenuItemClick` you cannot the read it back in `Button1_Click` as it is an entirely new instance.

Comment: Sidenote, you're concatenating strings together to form your SQL command. That makes your application highly vulnerable to a SQL Injection attack. You should switch to using parameterized queries.

Comment: Thanks Robinso and mason ! So how can i maintain my variable between these functions ?

Comment: I found my answer here with Viewstate : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31344/Beginner-s-Guide-To-View-State